# How do I create JLabels (or other elements) without repeating code?

Tags: java, swing, builder

I searched for a while and couldn't find anything about this. Say for instance I would be creating a lot of JLabels, but instead of retyping everything for every JLabel, I could have a method that would allow me to input what I wanted and have it create them for me. How would I go about doing that? I have a small example of what I mean below.

```
private JLabel LabelBuilder(JLabel label, String text, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    label = new JLabel(text);
    label.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    window.add(label);
}

public void SetupElements()
{
    LabelBuilder(labelName, "Text", 10, 10, 200, 20);
}
```

How would I go about returning it? Is there a more efficient way than this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: And then obviously you call your `LabelBuilder` in a loop, just like any other repeated code that you don't want to retype by hand.

Comment: Also for all that is holy don't call `setBounds()` on any Component.  Use a LayoutManager.

Comment: Method names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: Sorry, I am completely new to Java and I have no idea what much of this means. I just feel like it is unnecessary to retype all of this.

Comment: There's no need for the `label` argument to `LabelBuilder`; you can't return anything back to `LabelBuilder`'s caller through it anyway (if that's what you had in mind).  And if you change the method signature to `public void LabelBuilder(...)`, you don't have to _return_ anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

To answer **How would I go about returning it?**

```
    private void setupElements()
    {
        JLabel aLabel = labelBuilder("Text", 10, 10, 200, 20);
    }

    //No need for a `JLabel label` argument.
    //Method names start with lower case. see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/
    private JLabel labelBuilder(String text, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        //setting bounds is not recommended. Instead the parent container (window) needs 
        //to implemenent layout manager. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html
        label.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        window.add(label);
        return label;
    }
```